# Using Apache POI HSSF, how can I refresh all formula cells at once?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am filling cells of an Excel file using Apache POI, and there are a lot of formula cells in the document. However, their values are not refreshed when I open the document in Excel.

It's my understanding that I need to use a `FormulaEvaluator` to refresh formula cells. Is there a way, though, to update all formula cells at once? There are a *lot* of them, and while making an exhaustive list is not out of question, it's certainly not something I'm very willing to do.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Sure. Refreshing all the formulas in a workbook is possibly the more typical use case anyway.

If you're using HSSF, call [evaluatorAllFormulaCells](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAllFormulaCells(org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook)):

```
 HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(hssfWorkbook)
```

If you're using XSSF, call [evaluatorAllFormulaCells](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAllFormulaCells(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook)):

```
 XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(xssfWorkbook)
```

More details are available on the [poi website](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAllFormulaCells(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook))

Comment: What if I have some unsupported functions in my formula, for example DB or SLN? Is there any flag I can set to tell Excel to recalculate all formula cells once the file is opened?

Answer (score 9):

```
wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
// replace "wb" with your HSSFWorkbook/XSSFWorkbook object
```

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#setForceFormulaRecalculation-boolean-

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#setForceFormulaRecalculation-boolean-

Comment: It does not help me - conditional formatting has wrong values. Atleas if I open document in Libreoffice Calc