# Can't retrieve value of a computed cell using JExcelAPI

Tags: java, jexcelapi

This is my first post, please bear with me.  I'm trying to do something simple:  look at the value of a spreadsheet cell that contains a formula.  Nothing seems to work, instead of the correct answer (579) , I get "4".  (output below).  This program creates a simple spreadsheet with numbers in A1 and A2, and the sum in A3.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import jxl.*;
   import jxl.Workbook;
   import jxl.biff.FormulaData;
   import jxl.biff.formula.FormulaException;
   import jxl.write.Number;
   import jxl.write.*;
   import jxl.write.Formula;
   import jxl.read.biff.CellValue;

   public class ReadCell {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
                                     jxl.read.biff.BiffException,
                                     WriteException, FormulaException
     {
         String filename = "readcell.xls";
         WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename));
         WritableSheet ws = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);

         Number n = new Number(0,0,123);   // 123 in A1
         ws.addCell(n);
         n = new Number(0,1,456);          // 456 in A2
         ws.addCell(n);
         Formula f = new Formula(0,2, "A1+A2");  // formula in A3, yields 579
         ws.addCell(f);

         workbook.write();
         workbook.close();   

  //now try to retrieve the sum of A1 + A2, which is in A3 (value should be 579)
  Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook( new File (filename));
  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
  Cell cell = sheet.getCell("A3");

  System.out.println("\n\nCell A3 contents = " + cell.getContents());

  //that didn't work, maybe try it by casting to a NumberCell?
  NumberCell numbercell = (NumberCell)cell;
  System.out.println("NumberCell value = " + numbercell.getValue());
  System.out.println("NumberCell contents = " + numbercell.getContents());

  //that didn't work, maybe try it by casting to a FormulaCell?
  FormulaCell fc = (FormulaCell)cell;
  System.out.println("FormulaCell contents = " + fc.getContents());
  System.out.println("FormulaCell formula = " + fc.getFormula());

  //that didn't work, maybe try to get contents by casting to FormulaData?
  FormulaData fd = (FormulaData)cell;
  System.out.println("FormulaData contents = " + fd.getContents());
  System.out.println("FormulaData type = " + fd.getType());

  //that didn't work, maybe try to get contents by casting to NumberFormulaCell?
  NumberFormulaCell nfc = (NumberFormulaCell)cell;
  System.out.println("NumberFormulaCell value = " + nfc.getValue());
  System.out.println("NumberFormulaCell contents = " + nfc.getContents());
  System.out.println("NumberFormulaCell formula = " + nfc.getFormula());

  //that didn't work, try to get contents by casting to CellValue?
  CellValue cv = (CellValue)cell;
  System.out.println("cellValue contents = " + cv.getContents());

  //Nothing works and these casts won't compile:
  //Number nnn = (Number)cell;
  //NumberFormulaRecord nfr = (NumberFormulaRecord)cell; 

  wb.close();
  }
}
```

Here is the output, the "4"s should be "579"s

Cell A3 contents = 4

NumberCell value = 4.0

NumberCell contents = 4

FormulaCell contents = 4

FormulaCell formula = A1+A2

FormulaData contents = 4

FormulaData type = Numerical Formula

NumberFormulaCell value = 4.0

NumberFormulaCell contents = 4

NumberFormulaCell formula = A1+A2

cellValue contents = 4

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code that writes the workbook. Then I opened the workbook in Excel. When I told it to close, I was prompted with a message:"Microsoft Excel recalculates formulas when opening files last saved by an earlier version of Excel". After choosing to save, and then running the code that reads (but not the code that writes the workbook) I got the correct cell value of 579. When I deleted the file and ran all the code you posted, I got 4. It looks like the formula needs to be calculated before it can be read. This post seems to say there's no fixing it, and makes a supposition as to why: [Updated excel file still returns old values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200472/updated-excel-file-still-returns-old-values)