# Auto Refresh referenced cell written with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have xlsx document with one sheet.
In cell 'A2' i have a reference to cell 'A1'.

The following code writes data to cell 'A1'.

When I open the document, cell 'A2' is not updated with value of cell 'A1' automatically.
I am required to click on cell 'A2' and press enter, only then I see the new value.

What can be done so when document is opened the value will be updated?

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
XSSFWorkbook book = null;

String path = "c://temp//doc.xlsx";

inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

book = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

row.createCell(0).setCellValue("VALUE");

outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);

book.write(outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html

Comment: already asked before in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937373/using-apache-poi-hssf-how-can-i-refresh-all-formula-cells-at-once)