# Java API Automated formula's in Excel with trash output

Tags: java

I'm creating an automated Salary Specification and hourssheet for employees. I'm using `HSSFWorkbook` from API.

The formula is for total hours worked (which is `=+ALS(D10 < C10;(((D10+1)-C10)*24); D10-C10)*24))`

**The formula is without any doubt correct.**
However, the outcome is as follows.

[image: This picture shows the **direct** outcome]

When I click on enter on the formula, it just gives the desired outcome.

My code is as follows, where getMonday(weeknummer) returns the exact date of the monday of the weeknumber, getBegintijd is getBegintime, getEindtijd is getEndtime, welkerij is which row:

```
switch(i) {

        case 0:
            newCel.setCellValue(getMonday(weeknummer));
            beginCel.setCellValue(getBegintijd(name, getMonday(weeknummer)));
            endCel.setCellValue(getEindtijd(name, getMonday(weeknummer)));
            totaalCel.setCellFormula("ALS(D"+(welkerij+1) + "<C" + (welkerij+1) + ";(((D" + (welkerij+1) + "+1)-C" + (welkerij+1) + ")*24);(D" + (welkerij+1) + "-C" + (welkerij+1) + ")*24)");
        break;
```

Comment: Try to recalculate the formula: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5937590/7334796

Comment: Might it be the celltype? cellstyle?

Comment: @Jérôme Helped thanks bro. I'm sorry that in this case it might be a duplicate then.. Couldn't find that question with my searching terms :)